# certificate validation logic for single WebClient instance

Tags: c#, .net, validation, ssl

I'm using `MyWebClient` which inherits from `WebClient` to make http(s) requests.
I would like to skip SSL certificate validation for certain instances of `MyWebClient`. That's why I introduced property indicating whether or not validation of certificate should occur. However, when I try to set up validation callback like this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
```

the validation check is applied globally. I know that it's possible for `HttpWebRequest` to set `CertificateValidationCallback` which will be set on instance level. However I didn't found a way to set the same for WebClient.

Any ideas if that is possible? .Net 4.5.1

Comment: In Webclient i see there is getWebRequest method, that gives you WebRequest which is the parent class of HttpWebrequest, and most probably you can cast to it. i don't know if that's the way to do it, but its a good start. if that did not work for you i have another solution using the decorator pattern.

Comment: @RaniDevpr indeed good idea, I guess it should work. Thanks for suggestion, will try it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to override [`GetWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx), call the base implementation and cast it to an HttpWebRequest. From there you can add your custom, per WebClient instance check logic. Something similar to this:

```
class MyWC:WebClient
{

   public MyWC() {
       Validate = false;
   }

   public bool Validate {get;set;} // yes/no

   protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri url)
   {
        // this is called for each DownloadXXXX call
        var _req = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(url);

        // if Validate is true 
        if (Validate) {
            // set the callback on this request
            _req.ServerCertificateValidationCallback  = (s,cert,chain,polErr)=> {
                // do some check, only allow SE certificates here
                return cert.Subject.Contains(".stackexchange.com");
            };
        }
        return _req;
    }
}
```

Above class will be used like so:

```
var mywc = new MyWC();

mywc.Validate = true;

mywc.DownloadString("https://stackoverflow.com");
mywc.DownloadString("https://superuser.com/questions");
mywc.DownloadString("https://google.com"); // this will throw
// The underlying connection was closed: 
// Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

mywc.Validate = false;

mywc.DownloadString("https://google.com"); // this will  work


var normal = new WebClient();
normal.DownloadString("https://google.com"); // and the default webclient will work
// no global certificate validation
```